# xgettext output to specific folder

Tags: gettext

I am new using `xgettext` command. So I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I put the command:

```
xgettext -n *.php -o --output='/home/public/sample'
```

in my script, but I get an error:

```
xgettext: cannot create output file "--output=/home/public/sample": No such file or directory`
```

But when I run `xgettext -n *.php` - messages.po file gets created in my current directory! Is there a way to specify the location where to create `messages.po` file?

Comment: what does `ls -ld /home/public/sample` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write the output of `xgettext` to a specified file, use or `-o`, or `--output`, no both of them in the same time (in your case, `xgettext` will "think" to save the output in `--output='/home/public/sample'` which obviously can't be a file).

So, this will be correct:

```
xgettext -n *.php -o '/path/to/output_file'
```

which is equivalent with:

```
xgettext -n *.php --output='/path/to/output_file'
```

If you want that the output files to be placed in a specific directory, use:

```
xgettext -n *.php -p '/path/to/output_dir'
```

or, equivalent:

```
xgettext -n *.php --output-dir='/path/to/output_dir'
```

Also, be sure that `/path/to/output_file` file or `/path/to/output_dir` directory exists.

See also [`man xgettext`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xgettext).